How to write values into empty array from a loop dedicated to another function in Javascript?
I am doing a random sort of values according to the Fisher Yates method, and to explore the inside of this process I tried to out the random numbers (arsam1 is the number fixed set, iValue1 and jValue1 are empty arrays which are supposed to be filled with serial number i and the randomized number j).
I would like to print the arrays iValue1 and jValue1 on the screen.
When using the following code, outside of seeing the headers and button, I see no number at all. Where am I wrong?
I wrote the following code, and I hoped see, on top of the first headers and button 3 lines of numbers, the randomized array, the counter array iValue1, and the randomizer array Value. Instead, I got nothing.


const arsam1 = [5, 10, 15, 18, 6, 3, 9, 23, 29, 17, 12, 40];
let iValue1 = [];
let jValue1 = [];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arsam2;

function myFunction() {
  for (let i = arsam1.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let iValue1[i] = i;
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let jValue1[i] = j;
    let k = arsam1[i];
    arsam1[i] = arsam1[j];
    arsam1[j] = k;
  }
}

document.getElementById("iValue").innerHTML = iValue1;
document.getElementById("jValue").innerHTML = jValue1;
<h1>string Templates</h1>
<p>check up string templates</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Randomize</button>
<p id="iValue"></p>
<p id="jValue"></p>




The code shows the arrays when the page loads and they're empty, but there's nothing there that would show the arrays when the button is clicked

Put the last 2 innerHTML assignments at the end of myFunction().

let iValue1[i] = i; is invalid syntax. You don't use let in assignments, only when declaring a new variable.

You need to initialize iValue1 and jValue1 outside of the myFunction to maintain their values after the function is executed, Also inside your for loop you need to set values to iValue1 and jValue1 array correctly.
Once after above is completed you need to update the HTML template to reflect the changes.
Refer the code below:


const arsam1 = [5, 10, 15, 18, 6, 3, 9, 23, 29, 17, 12, 40];
let iValue1 = [];
let jValue1 = [];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Original Array: [${arsam1.join(', ')}]`; // Show Original Array

function myFunction() {
  for (let i = arsam1.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    let temp = arsam1[i]; // Keep a temp variable to hold a value temperorily and swap.
    arsam1[i] = arsam1[j];
    arsam1[j] = temp;
    iValue1[i] = i; // Set iValue1 and jValue1 with current indexes
    jValue1[i] = j; // Set iValue1 and jValue1 with current indexes
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `Shuffled Array: [${arsam1.join(', ')}]`;
  document.getElementById("iValue").innerHTML = `iValue1: [${iValue1.join(', ')}]`;
  document.getElementById("jValue").innerHTML = `jValue1: [${jValue1.join(', ')}]`;
}
<html>
<body>

  <h1>Shuffle Example</h1>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Randomize</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="iValue"></p>
  <p id="jValue"></p>
</body>
</html>




@AdamGivon appreciate if you can mark it as correct and give an upvote too
